# What does the C++ standard says for algorithms when first <= last is not fulfilled?

Tags: c++, algorithm, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, std

What does the official C++ standard says about the algorithms when the condition `first <= last` is not fulfilled, `first` and `last` being the iterators passed to one of the standard algorithms?

I see three possibities:

- The algorithms are required to check the condition so that if it not fullfilled, the algorithm do not do anything
- The algorithms are required to throw an exception
- This is undefined behaviour, so... anything can happen

I am puzzled, because in the algorithms description I don't see a `requires` clause concerning `first` and `last`.

EDIT1: This was a simplification of the question. A more exact version is "what happen to the algorithms when `last` is not reachable from `first` by successively applying `operator++`?

EDIT2: I am asking this question because I am implementing an specialization of `std::reverse` and I was wondering whether I should check this condition, or if I can allow the function to do something completely wrong when `last` is not reachable from `first`?

Comment: when the condition is not fulfilled, it simply returns false.

Comment: @PankajKumarThapa Read the question... What happen when I do a `std::sort(first, last)` when `last` comes before `first`?

Comment: Your question is based on the premise that algorithms require this ordering, but you close with a statement saying you have no evidence for this claim. What are you asking, really?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I modified the question accordingly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text you're looking for is in the iterators section (emphasis mine):

> [iterator.requirements.general]/7-8
>
> > An iterator j is called reachable from an iterator i if and only if there is a finite sequence of applications of
> >     the expression ++i that makes i == j. If j is reachable from i, they refer to elements of the same sequence.
> >
> > Most of the library’s algorithmic templates that operate on data structures have interfaces that use ranges.
> >     A range is a pair of iterators that designate the beginning and end of the computation. A range [i,i) is an
> >     empty range; **in general, a range [i,j) refers to the elements in the data structure starting with the element
> >     pointed to by i and up to but not including the element pointed to by j. Range [i,j) is valid if and only if
> >     j is reachable from i. The result of the application of functions in the library to invalid ranges is undefined.**

The standard explicitly says here that passing an invalid (not fulfilled) range to standard algorithms results in undefined behaviour. The algorithms themselves do specify ranges in the `[first, last)` format.

Note that /7 disallows swapping the arguments for random access iterators because you cannot apply `++first` over and over to reach `last`.

Comment: There you go :)